# Using the new sse registers xmm8 - xmm15

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, cpu-registers

Is it possible to use the new SSE registers from Visual Studio 2010 inline assembler? If so, how and what else conditions must be satisfied? I don't know for example if new registers are available in both x86 and x64 modes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline assembly is not allowed when compiling for the x64 platform in Visual Studio (since VS 2005).

I would recommend that you use [intrinsics instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx). It makes the compiler handle the CPU registers for you, and does some instruction reordering (the optimizer gets to process the code, which is never the case with inline assembly).

Comment: +1 for recommending intrinsics over assembler. Note also that xmm8..xmm15 are only available for x86-64 code.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ is also pretty good.  Other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info

Answer (score 3):

As regards your 2nd question:

> I don't know for example if new
>   registers are available in both x86
>   and x64 modes.

The 'new' registers `xmm8` - `xmm15` are **only** available in 64-bit mode.

Note however, the situation with the new AVX registers (for CPUs and OSes that support AVX, e.g. Sandy Bridge CPU  + Win7 SP1):

`ymm0` - `ymm7` are available in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

`ymm8` - `ymm15` are available only in 64-bit mode.

Comment: The same to the new AVX-512, only the low 8 registers are available in 32-bit mode, so you need to go 64-bit if you don't want to "waste" the remaining 24 registers